# Python Threading Over a Counter

Tags: python

I have a function that needs to be called N times. I would like T threads to execute the function in parallel. How would you model this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And now, for some alternative fun :)

```
import threading
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool   # this is a THREAD POOL! undocumented :)


def execute_me():
    print threading.current_thread().name, 'python is fun'


tp = ThreadPool(processes=4)
print tp.map(lambda x: x(), repeat(execute_me, 4))
```

Output:

```
% python mpthreadpool.py 
Thread-1 python is fun
 Thread-2 python is fun
Thread-3 python is fun
Thread-3 python is fun
[None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
threads = []
for i in range(NUM_THREADS):
    t = threading.Thread(target=your_function, args=your_argslist)
    t.start()  # if you want to start it immediately, otherwise you can defer it 
    threads.append(t)
```

Comment: OP asked for a model, not an implementation. Also you might consider using a deque if you will be frequently adding and removing objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of Python is that it not supports OS-based threads because of the famous GIL (see http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/01/python-threads-and-the-global-interpreter-lock/).  The easiest method to use real threading (for example n threads) in my opinion is to use parallel python (see http://www.parallelpython.com/) in combination with the parallel map version for parallel python (http://honeypot.net/yet-another-python-map).  This can be used as follows:

```
def func(arg1):
   # do something with arg1
   return result

import pp
import ppmap

ppmap.ppmap(n, func, [test1, ... test2])
```

Comment: but threading in python is not intented as a lightweight process, but instead a logical thread. You can use heavyweight threads (i.e. processes) for true cuncurrency, but then you don't share state. The reason for this is that in other languages this middle ground is often seen as a cure-all, abused, and then picked on as a source of all bugs.

Answer (score 0):

```
for t in threadpool:
   t.execute(function)
```

Comment: where does the N times come in?

Comment: @BiggAl @fabrizio there's no builtin threadpool concept with Python, so without additional information, this isn't a useful answer

Comment: the OP asks for a MODEL not an implementation. This is one model.